# Tor + Homebrew & Mavericks OpenSSL

Tags: macos, openssl, osx-mavericks, homebrew, tor

I'm trying to install the command-line version of Tor. I have actually already done so using Homebrew, but it gives me the following notice:

```
[notice] Your OpenSSL version seems to be 0.9.8y. We recommend 1.0.0 or later.
```

So I updated OpenSSL. `openssl version` now yields in `1.0.1f`.

When I run `which openssl` in Terminal, it returns with `/usr/local/bin/openssl`.
When I run `which tor` in Terminal, it returns with `/usr/local/bin/tor`.

So why isn't Tor seeing the updated version of OpenSSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Tor via Homebrew and installed it again via Homebrew. I needed to have my $PATH set BEFORE I installed Tor. Doing this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> So why isn't Tor seeing the updated version of OpenSSL?

Mac OS X will do as much as it can to load 0.9.8 in `/usr/lib`:

```
$ find /usr/ -iname libssl*
/usr//lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
/usr//lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
/usr//lib/libssl.dylib
```

`LD_PRELOAD` is not honored on Mac OS X (IIRC). Try using `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. But be sure your Tor linked against 1.0.1, and not 0.9.8. Otherwise, you'll catch obscure errors that make no sense.

---

> When I run which tor in Terminal, it returns with /usr/local/bin/tor

Did you build Tor yourself? If you built it yourself, then here's a few notes from the field with respect to Apple's linkers. (1) they silently ignore `rpath`'s. (2) they silently ignore requests like `-Bstatic`. (3) more generally, they always link to the shared object if available (even on iOS where the only thing you are suppose to use is an archive). (4) LD_PRELOAD is not honored.

You have to be persistent to link to the OpenSSL in `/usr/local/ssl/`. The best way I have found is to remove `-L`, remove `-lssl` and remove `-lcrypto` from the makefiles; and add the full path names of the static archive at `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a` and `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a`.